# Create a "feed" from one WordPress site to another?

Tags: rss, feed, xml-rpc

I know there a way to use XML-RPC to transfer past posts from one WordPress site to another, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a constantly updating feed of posts of a certain type. That way when a post is added to one site it is simultaneously added to the other (one site being the feeder and the other only being able to display the posts).

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the feed with core functions and insert new post in the other install. You can write or buy a plugin for doing this. The important functions for this scenario is 'fetch_feed' and 'wp_insert_post'. It is also useful, if you change the default cache, if you have often new posts, more as in 12hours.